# Javascript - Count array objects that have a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I'm getting an array returned to me and I need to count the rows that have a value in them

I've tried to call arr.length but that gives me the total length of the array

```
var arr = [
  { id: '1', '': '' },
  { id: '2', '': '' },
  { id: '3', '': '' },
  { id: '4', '': '' },
  { id: '', '': '' },
  { id: '', '': '' },
  { id: '', '': '' }
]
```

The result should be 4.

Answer (score 11):

Use filter to only capture keys with value, and return the resulting array's length.

```js
var arr = [ { id: '1', '': '' },{ id: '2', '': '' },{ id: '3', '': '' },{ id: '4', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' } ]

var res = arr.filter(val => {
    return val.id
})
console.log(res.length)
```

Comment: You could simplify the filter to look like this `arr.filter(val => val.id)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this. This checks for all the keys in the object:

```js
const arr = [{id:'1','':''},{id:'2','':''},{id:'3','':''},{id:'4','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''}]

const count = arr.reduce((r,a) => Object.values(a).some(v => v) ? ++r: r, 0)
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var count = 0;
for (var x of arr) {
  if (x.id != '') {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Basically what I do is that loop through all the object and if it's not an empty string, then count it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to add the items up if `id.length > 0`

```js
var arr = [ { id: '1', '': '' },
{ id: '2', '': '' },
{ id: '3', '': '' },
{ id: '4', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' },
{ id: '', '': '' } ]


let count = arr.reduce((val, itm) => itm.id.length > 0 ? val + 1 : val + 0, 0)

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach through the array and check if the id key has a value

```js
var output = 0;
var arr = [ { id: '1', '': '' },{ id: '2', '': '' },{ id: '3', '': '' },{ id: '4', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' } ]

arr.forEach(e => {
  if (e["id"] != '') {
    output++;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count if a row has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

```js
var array = [ { id: '1', '': '' }, { id: '2', '': '' }, { id: '3', '': '' }, { id: '4', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }, { id: '', '': '' }],
    count = array.reduce((s, o) => s + Object.values(o).some(Boolean), 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

List item

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce

```js
var arr = [ { id: '1', '': '' },{ id: '2', '': '' },{ id: '3', '': '' },{ id: '4', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' },{ id: '', '': '' } ]

console.log(arr.reduce((acc,e)=>{e.id!=''?acc++:false; return acc},0))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are a fan of Lodash, you can use `countBy` ([documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy))

```js
const array = [{id:'1','':''},{id:'2','':''},{id:'3','':''},{id:'4','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''},{id:'','':''}]

// The iterator function `obj => obj.id === ''` returns Boolean value `true` or `false`
const count = _.countBy(array, obj => obj.id !== '');

// Get the `true` value
console.log(count.true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

One liner fans:

```
_.countBy(array, obj => obj.id !== '').true;
```